# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed

Tags: java, web-services, postgresql, jdbc

I am connecting to postgres data base using java web services (**apache axis**) with **JDBC** connections to get the data.But suddenly in most of times i am getting an exception of `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.` and some times it is working fine. Here I am using many prepared statements. My sample code is

```
Connection connection=null;
try
{
    Class.forName(driver);
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    ps1=connection.prepareStatement("select * from emp");
    rs1=ps1.executeQuery();
    while(rs1.next())
    {            
        ps2=connection.prepareStatement("select * from dept where dept_no="+rs1.getInt("dept_no"));
        rs2=ps2.executeQuery();
        while(rs2.next())
        {
            ................
            ................
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Exception occurred is"+e.getMessage());            
}
finally
{
    try{if(rs1!=null)rs1.close();}catch(Exception e){ System.out.println("*1closing error--->"+e);}
    try{if(ps1!=null)ps1.close();}catch(Exception e){ System.out.println("**1closing error--->"+e);}
    try{if(rs2!=null)rs2.close();}catch(Exception e){ System.out.println("*2closing error--->"+e);}
    try{if(ps2!=null)ps2.close();}catch(Exception e){ System.out.println("**2closing error--->"+e);}
    try{if(connection!=null)connection.close();}catch(Exception e){ System.out.println("***closing error--->"+e);}
}
```

stack trace about this exception is

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:137)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:124)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:30)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.Jdbc3Connection.<init>(Jdbc3Connection.java:24)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:386)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:260)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.codon.service.WareHouseServer.get_picks(WareHouseServer.java:7415)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.readMore(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:135)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:104)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.read(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:73)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.ReceiveChar(PGStream.java:259)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:254)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:95)
    ... 37 more
```

I checked the postgres logs and i found the following statements in different cases

1.WARNING:  worker took too long to start; cancelled.

2.could not reattach to shared memory (key=...., addr=.....): 487.

3.could not receive data from client: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

4.unexpected EOF on client connection.

please help me.Thanks In advance

Comment: You need to show the *full* exception stack trace, since the nested exception(s) will contain the details of the problem. Given that you're not using pooled connections I won't be surprised if you're hitting max_connections issues, but without the full error it's hard to say.

Comment: Are you closing all prepared statements and resultsets? In a given example closing of ps2 and rs2 is hidden

Comment: I updated the question with stack trace about the exception and last time i forgot to post the `ps2` and `rs2` closing statements.I did it in the application.

Comment: PostgreSQL server version and host operating system? Could it be a Windows server by any chance?

Comment: Hi @Sasi Vara Prasad, I'm expecting the same issue with same postgresql logs. I'm using the default hibernate connection pooling. were you manage to fix this ?

Answer (score 22):

The real problem is:

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read
```

The connection was closed when Java tried to read from it. This can be caused by:

- The PostgreSQL server being restarted
- The PostgreSQL backend you were connected to being terminated
- The PostgreSQL backend you were connected to crashing
- Dodgy network connection
- Badly behaved stateful firewalls
- Idle connections timing out of the NAT connection tables of NAT firewall/routers

... and probably more. Check the PostgreSQL server logs to see if there's anything informative there; also consider doing some network tracing with a tool like Wireshark.

Comment: I updated my question with statements in log files of postgres

Answer (score 3):

Try chekin Postgresql version, in my case I deployed my app with:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
```

But in local I used 42.2.18 and worked fine, so I din't know after checking version, so you should try another versions maybe.

Answer (score 2):

**Fixed for me:**

hop onto the `pg_hba.conf` file and under IPV4 connection change its `127.xxxx` to the `0.0.0.0/0`

double check: hop onto the `postgresql.conf`  and change the `listenaddresses` to `*` (im sure you know that you need to delete the starting `#` first in order to make it work)

Good luck!