# Micronaut + PostgreSQL + Docker-compose issue

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, micronaut

I'm trying to run a Micronaut service that uses PostgreSQL on a docker-compose file. But I'm having the following issue:

```
21:12:32.741 [main] INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
21:12:33.744 [main] ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:315)
at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:225)
at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465)
at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:81)
at io.micronaut.configuration.jdbc.hikari.HikariUrlDataSource.<init>(HikariUrlDataSource.java:35)
at io.micronaut.configuration.jdbc.hikari.DatasourceFactory.dataSource(DatasourceFactory.java:66)
at io.micronaut.configuration.jdbc.hikari.$DatasourceFactory$DataSource0Definition.build(Unknown Source)
at io.micronaut.context.BeanDefinitionDelegate.build(BeanDefinitionDelegate.java:153)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1979)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingletonInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:2768)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingleton(DefaultBeanContext.java:2754)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanForDefinition(DefaultBeanContext.java:2425)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:2399)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1264)
at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanDefinition.getBeanForConstructorArgument(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:1014)
at io.micronaut.configuration.hibernate.jpa.$EntityManagerFactoryBean$HibernateStandardServiceRegistry0Definition.doBuild(Unknown Source)
at io.micronaut.context.AbstractParametrizedBeanDefinition.build(AbstractParametrizedBeanDefinition.java:118)
at io.micronaut.context.BeanDefinitionDelegate.build(BeanDefinitionDelegate.java:149)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1979)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingletonInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:2768)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingleton(DefaultBeanContext.java:2754)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanForDefinition(DefaultBeanContext.java:2425)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:2399)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1264)
at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanDefinition.getBeanForConstructorArgument(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:1014)
at io.micronaut.configuration.hibernate.jpa.$EntityManagerFactoryBean$HibernateMetadataSources1Definition.doBuild(Unknown Source)
at io.micronaut.context.AbstractParametrizedBeanDefinition.build(AbstractParametrizedBeanDefinition.java:118)
at io.micronaut.context.BeanDefinitionDelegate.build(BeanDefinitionDelegate.java:149)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1979)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingletonInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:2768)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingleton(DefaultBeanContext.java:2754)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.loadContextScopeBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2292)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.initializeContext(DefaultBeanContext.java:1562)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.initializeContext(DefaultApplicationContext.java:234)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.readAllBeanDefinitionClasses(DefaultBeanContext.java:2905)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.start(DefaultBeanContext.java:231)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.start(DefaultApplicationContext.java:180)
at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.start(Micronaut.java:71)
at org.wcode.author.service.ApplicationKt.main(Application.kt:10)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: st-database
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:220)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:231)
at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:95)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:98)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213)
... 46 common frames omitted
```

### Files definition

Following is the definition of the files that I'm using on my current project.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  st-author-service:
    image: author-service:latest
    environment:
      - JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://st-database:5432/sentency_db
      - JDBC_USER=<USERNAME>
      - JDBC_PASSWORD=<PASSWORD>
      - JDBC_DRIVER=org.postgresql.Driver
    depends_on:
      - st-database
    networks:
      - database-network
      - internal

  st-database:
    image: postgres:13.3-alpine
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - database.env # configure postgres
    volumes:
      - database-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    networks:
      - database-network

volumes:
  database-data:

networks:
  database-network:
    driver: bridge
    external: false
  internal:
```

**application.yml**

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: authorService
  server:
    port: 7000

datasources:
  default:
    url: ${JDBC_URL:`jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE`}
    username: ${JDBC_USER:sa}
    password: ${JDBC_PASSWORD:""}
    driverClassName: ${JDBC_DRIVER:org.h2.Driver}
    schema-generate: CREATE_DROP

jpa:
  default:
    entity-scan:
      packages: 'org.wcode.author.service.domain.entities'
    properties:
      hibernate:
        hbm2ddl:
          auto: update
        show_sql: true
```

### Tests

I tested the `application.yml` pointing to a PostgreSQL database deployed on Docker and it worked, the problem started when I tried to use docker-compose to structure the deployment. To check if the network definition was working I deployed pgAdmin together with that configuration and I was able to connect to the database.

After that specific line:

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: st-database
```

I come to the conclusion that the issue was caused by the host not being found.

I already made a lot of research and haven't found a way to solve that problem. I can't see what I'm missing.

Thanks in advance for all the help.

## Update

I was able to get the connection log from the PostgreSQL container and only pgAdmin connection is appearing, the service is not even reaching the container to connect. The network being used is the same. Here is the log:

```
2021-08-10 15:43:13.465 GMT [100] LOG: connection received: host=sentency-deploy_pgAdmin_1.sentency-deploy_database-network port=40848
2021-08-10 15:43:13.466 GMT [100] LOG: connection authorized: user=user database=postgres
2021-08-10 15:43:13.478 GMT [101] LOG: connection received: host=sentency-deploy_pgAdmin_1.sentency-deploy_database-network port=40850
2021-08-10 15:43:13.479 GMT [101] LOG: connection authorized: user=user database=sentency_db
2021-08-10 15:43:13.491 GMT [102] LOG: connection received: host=sentency-deploy_pgAdmin_1.sentency-deploy_database-network port=40852
2021-08-10 15:43:13.493 GMT [102] LOG: connection authorized: user=user database=postgres
2021-08-10 15:43:17.750 GMT [103] LOG: connection received: host=sentency-deploy_pgAdmin_1.sentency-deploy_database-network port=40858
```

Now I think the problem could be the way I'm building the image. My current Dockerfile is:

```
FROM ghcr.io/graalvm/graalvm-ce:ol7-java11-21.2.0 as build
WORKDIR /author-service
COPY . /author-service
RUN yum install -y -q xz
RUN curl -sL -o - https://github.com/upx/upx/releases/download/v3.96/upx-3.96-amd64_linux.tar.xz | tar xJ
RUN gu install native-image
RUN ./gradlew assemble
RUN native-image --no-fallback --static -jar /author-service/build/libs/author-service-*-all.jar service
RUN ./upx-3.96-amd64_linux/upx -7 /author-service/service

FROM scratch
EXPOSE 7000:7000
COPY --from=build /author-service/service /service
ENTRYPOINT ["./service"]
```

That's giving me an image of 27.67MB.

Comment: If you specify `container_name: st-database` under `services: st-database`, does that help?

Comment: Hi @JeffScottBrown I tried but the error is the same.

Comment: I am sorry that I can't help but the error indicates that the problem probably doesn't have anything to do with Micronaut or with Postgres but instead is a network config issue in Docker.  At least that is my suspicion.  Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks, @JeffScottBrown. that's exactly what I was thinking, but I'm not able to solve it sine the setup is there and the connection with Postgres is working

Comment: Though I'm with @JeffScottBrown on this one, I would still check the postgres logs and see what happened to the connection attempt to rule out any misconfig of `pg_hba.conf` and/or `postresql.conf`.. Also have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806083/org-postgresql-util-psqlexception-the-connection-attempt-failed) to get some inspiration for your `Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: st-database`-issue.

Comment: "I would still check the postgres logs and see what happened to the connection attempt" - That is a fine idea, but I expect that postgres isn't even seeing the connection request.  It looks like the client is unable to reach the db host.

Comment: this is a simple docker network issue. to isolate the problem start without declaring networks. I‘m sure it will work with the default network. If yes, you can start to investigate what’s wrong with your custom network settings

Comment: Hi @saw303. I removed all the network declarations and the problem still persisted.

Comment: did you make sure the old network has bern deleted? stop your composition and then run docker network prune

Comment: Yes @saw303. I removed all the networks and even volumes stopped the composition and then started again. The error persisted.

Answer (score 0):

From the docker [compose documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/): `depends_on` *does not wait for [st-database] to be “ready”*. So maybe this is caused by the Postgres database not being ready to accept connections at the time your app tries to. The `UnknownHostException` is a bit strange in that case but that may depend on when docker is binding the port. To fix the problem you would need to write a script that waits for readiness as in the [second example here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/).

Comment: Hi @eso. What I did to test was, I initialized only the database with the command: ```docker-compose up -d st-database```. I checked the log until the database was ready to accept connections and initialized the service container with ```docker-compose up -d st-author-service```. Still showing the same error

Comment: Then it seems that the host really isn't found. Have you tried without the explicit network settings for database-network? I have been using Micronaut services with Postgres  running as a container (although not in the same docker compose file) so in general it should work.

Comment: when you say without the explicit network you mean using the default one of the docker-compose environment? The JDBC would be something like that```postgresql://bridge:5432/sentency_db```?

Comment: I just noticed that your st-database doesn't publish the postgres port 5432. That may be the reason why docker doesn't create a host address.

Comment: I just added 
```
ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

And still not working, the same error related to the host

Comment: I also just noticed that your application.yml above is configured for an H2 database. Did you really use Postgres for your tests?

Comment: that setup in the application.yml will use the environment variable being passed on the docker-compose file. The H2 is a fallback in case I don't place anything on the environment variables. I use that on the unit tests but for production can even be removed. For example, if I wrap the URL with quotes it will show an error that the URI should start with JDBC keyword and show the address that was passed on the environment variable